# Rvalue reference losing its nature

Tags: c++

I don't understand the following:

```
class Class {
  public:
  void operator=(string&&) {
      cout << "here";
  }
};

string func() {
    return "Paul";
}

int main()
{
    string&& rvalueref = func();

    Class obj;
    obj = rvalueref; <- error! Why isn't rvalueref a rvalue ref anymore?

    return 0;
}
```

since I can bind a prvalue to a rvalue reference, I thought I could also pass it around. Why does the above fail?

Comment: `rvalueref` is an lvalue. Rvalue references don't bind to lvalues.

Comment: @chris Did you mean to say lvalues don't bind to rvalue references?

Comment: @0x499602D2, I've likely been going off of [this title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object) the entire time. Or compiler errors like *non-const lvalue reference to type 'int' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'int'*

Comment: rvalueref is an lvalue?? But I just declared it a rvalue reference!

Comment: @Albert, Its type is rvalue reference to `int`. Its value category is lvalue.

Comment: @Albert: It's an lvalue with an rvalue reference type... confusing, I know. You need to say `obj = std::move(rvalueref)` for it to get its 'rvalue-ness' back.

Comment: @chris: I think you mean `std::string`, not `int`

Answer (score 1):

I believe `std::move` is what you're looking to use. (defined in`<utility>`) 
That way you can turn the lvalue into an rvalue.

```
//...
int main()
{
    string&& rvalueref = func();

    Class obj;
    obj = std::move(rvalueref);

    return 0;
}
```

If you wish to read more about it, information about the move semantics and rvalue references can be found [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html)

Answer (score 1):

The "rvalue" in "rvalue reference" is talking about *what the reference can bind to*.  Once it is bound, it's just a reference.  There's no difference between a bound rvalue reference and a bound lvalue reference.

Named variables are lvalues. ("variable" means object or reference). To produce an xvalue, i.e. an expression with rvalue reference type, you will have to use `std::move` or equivalent.